# use multiple sqlite databases in one application xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

How do i identify multiple **sqlite** databases in my app at run time. I am making a quiz app for iphone in which i need 5-6 sqlite databases, one for each category(subject) of quiz. Help anyone

Comment: I don't really think you need different databases for each category. This sounds like a really bad database design to me. At this stage in your project, is remodeling the database structure an option? You could do it in a better way

Comment: Yes, i can remodel it in any way u advice..please tell me the way

Comment: I gave you an alternate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this would be too long to post as a comment and it does somehow address your question, 
I would suggest again to use a different structure for your application because having multiple databases is not practical for such a simple thing as a quiz.

You can find some database structure examples here [Storing a multiple choice quiz in a database - deciding the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082751/storing-a-multiple-choice-quiz-in-a-database-deciding-the-schema) or here [Database Design For Developing 'Quiz' Web Application using PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102521/database-design-for-developing-quiz-web-application-using-php-and-mysql)

Assuming you have simple quizzes with different categories, a possible alternative would be to store your categories in a **Categories** table.

```
* Category
    - category_id (integer)
    - category_name (string/text)
```

Where the id would be unique for each one. You could have, for example, the category *sports* with the id 1 and the category *history* with the id 2.

The questions could be stored in another table, named **Questions**

```
* Questions
    - question_id (integer)
    - question_category (integer)
    - question_text (string/text)
    - question_correct_answer_id (integer)
```

You can have question 1: *For what team played John Doe?*. In the `question_category` field you put 1, since 1 is the id of the Sports category. In the `question_correct_answer_id` you will store the id of the correct answer (not the answer itself, just the id)

Last but not least, an **Answers** table.

```
* Answers
    - answer_id (integer)
    - question_id (integer)
    - answer_text (string/text)
```

Here `answer_id` is the id of the answer, you can store it in the **Questions** table if it's the correct one, and a `question_id` to identify the question.

Then you can do something like:

```
`SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE 'question_category' = 1`
```

and get all the Sports questions.
And for each question, you can do

```
SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE 'question_id' = 'your question's id'
```

Be careful, my examples aren't necessary the best solution, it's just a basic example that uses just a single database, but with multiple tables instead of multiple databases.

My advice to you would be to consider this alternative and if you think it's worth it, read a little about databases and design a better one.

Good luck!

Comment: thats appreciable..but i have to implement in-app purchase also in my quiz so that might not be helpful as the purchase quiz pack would be a database in itself

Comment: You don't sell the database, just its content. It's like being a library and giving customers a new bookshelf for each purchase. If you want to sell quiz packs, you just need to sell packs of questions/answers that can be inserted in the already existing database. What if you need to add a new pack to the app? You will need to update the app and add a new database, right? By using a single database, you can add as many packs as you want. The query data can be taken from your site, as xml files for example, and then inserted in the already existing database.

Comment: In the end, it's your call, but usingle  multiple db is waaay too overkill, difficult and not efficient. You should very rarely need to use more than one db ( http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/21507-when-to-use-multiple-databases/ )

Answer (score 7):

Use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) that is easy.

Identifing a database is simple, i dont't understand the problem...

```
FMDatabase *dbQuestions = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/tmpA.db"];
FMDatabase *dbAnswers   = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/tmpB.db"];
FMDatabase *dbPeople    = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/tmpC.db"];
[...]
[dbQuestions open]
[dbAnswers open]
[dbPeople open]
[...]
```

cheers.